# Squares in division ring extensions $\ell/k$ with $[\ell:k] = 2$

Tags: galois-theory, quadratic-forms, division-rings, field-extensions

Let $k$ and $\ell$ be division rings such that $\ell$ contains $k$, and $[\ell : k] = 2$. When do I know that there is an element $a \in k$ such that $x^2 = a$ has solutions in $\ell$, but not in $k$?

Comment: Since the dimension of a division ring over its centre is a square, we have that $2[k : Z(k)] = [\ell : k][k : Z(k)]$ equals $[\ell : Z(\ell)][Z(\ell) : Z(k)]$, and hence that $[Z(\ell) : Z(k)]$ is $2$ modulo squares.  In particular, if $Z(k)$ is not of characteristic $2$, then there should be an element of $Z(k)$ that is a square in $Z(\ell)$ but not in $Z(k)$.  But of course that doesn't mean that it isn't a square in $k$.

Comment: Do you have a condition you like in the commutative case?